# Terraform number variable validation not throwing error

Tags: terraform

I have a `network` module with variable:

```
variable "subnetsCount" {
  type = number
  description = "Define amount of subnets between 2 min and 4 max"
  validation {
    condition = var.subnetsCount < 2 || var.subnetsCount > 4
    error_message = "Variable subnetsCount should be between 2 and 4."
  }
  default = 2
}
```

I want to only allow a number value between 2 and 4. When I pass any value greater or smaller say 1 or 10 it doesn't throw any errors why?

1.For example I pass this to subnet:

```
module "network" {
  source = "./network"
  subnetsCount = 4
}
```

2. then type in terminal `terraform apply`, yet no errors thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```
condition = var.subnetsCount >= 2 && var.subnetsCount <= 4
```